# Referencing options in a borrowed context

Tags: rust

I'd like to be able to unwrap an optional inside a borrowed context. For example, to `println!` some value:

```
struct Optional {
    v: Option<String>,
    v2: Option<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut optionals = vec![];
    optionals.push(Optional { v: Some("foo".to_string()), v2: Some("bar".to_string())});
    optionals.push(Optional { v: None, v2: None });

    for optional in &optionals {
        println!("v:{} v2:{}", optional.v.unwrap_or("none".to_string()), optional.v2.unwrap_or("none".to_string()));
    }
}
```

My understanding is that, this isn't possible because `optional` is borrowed and `unwrap_or` consumes it's input, which is disallowed because it's borrowed. I tried to take a `ref` to the struct values but failed again, how can achieve what I want without consuming `optionals`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Option::as_ref`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref). In your example, you also have to deal with the fact that you need to match the type of a `&String` to the default value.

```
let v = optional.v.as_ref().map(|s| s as &str).unwrap_or("none");
let v2 = optional.v2.as_ref().map(|s| s as &str).unwrap_or("none");
println!("v:{} v2:{}", v, v2);
```

As [ker points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990871/referencing-options-in-a-borrowed-context/35991252?noredirect=1#comment59635548_35991252), you can also map [`AsRef::as_ref`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html#tymethod.as_ref):

```
let v = optional.v.as_ref().map(AsRef::as_ref).unwrap_or("none");
let v2 = optional.v2.as_ref().map(AsRef::as_ref).unwrap_or("none");
println!("v:{} v2:{}", v, v2);
```

As [qthree points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990871/referencing-options-in-a-borrowed-context/35991252?noredirect=1#comment59715346_35991252), there's a shorter version of `.map().unwrap()`. Tools like [Rust Clippy](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy) can help you find these when you don't have a legion of good programmers looking at your code ;-):

```
let v = optional.v.as_ref().map_or("none", |s| s as &str);
let v2 = optional.v2.as_ref().map_or("none", AsRef::as_ref);
println!("v:{} v2:{}", v, v2);
```

> Is this the most idiomatic way to print an optional in a borrowed context?

It's debatable. For example, if the value printed `"none"`, there'd be no way for the reader to know if it was actually `Some("none")` or `None`. Does that distinction matter for the operation of your code?

If I were printing data to the terminal for programmer consumption, I'd be more likely to just print using the [`Debug`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) formatter:

```
println!("v:{:?} v2:{:?}", optional.v, optional.v2);
```

Although I'd really just derive `Debug` for `Optional` and print the whole thing:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Optional { ... }
```

```
for optional in &optionals {
    println!("{:?}", optional);
}
```

If it was truly for user consumption, I might have differing phrases:

```
match optional.v {
    Some(ref s) => println!("The value is: {}", s),
    None => println!("The value is not set"),
};
```

Comment: i think `.map(AsRef::as_ref)` would be cleaner than `as`

Comment: Thanks @Shepmaster, this does the trick. Is this the most idiomatic way to print an optional in a borrowed context?

Comment: `let v = optional.v.as_ref().map_or("none", AsRef::as_ref);`